# Find key in hash table C

Tags: c, pointers, find, key, hashtable

I need help to write a function called find inside my program, which takes a key and a reference to an integer, fills in the reference with the appropriate value (if found), and returns 1 (true). If the key is not found, return 0 (false). You may assume that p already points to a valid location. So:

```
int find( char *key, int *p );
```

Can be called like this:

```
char *name = "Bob";
int data;
if( find( name, &data ))
   printf( "Found %s.  (S)he's %i\n\n", name, data );
else
   printf( "\nCouldn't find %s\n\n", name );
```

This is the program I have:

```
#define TABLE_SIZE  7
#define NUM_INPUTS  7

int hash( char *s )
{
   return strlen( s ) % TABLE_SIZE ;
}

typedef struct entry
{
   char *key;
   int   val;
   struct entry *next;
} entry;

entry* table[ TABLE_SIZE ] = { NULL };

void insert( char *s, int v )
{
   int h = hash( s );
   entry *t = (entry*) malloc( sizeof( entry ));

   t->key = s;
   t->val = v;
   t->next = table[h];
   table[h] = t;
}

int main()
{
   char* keyList[] = { "Jaga", "Jesse", "Cos", "Kate", "Nash", "Vera",
      "Bob" };

   int valList[] = { 24, 78, 86, 28, 11, 99, 38 };

   int i;

   for( i=0; i<NUM_INPUTS; ++i )
      insert( keyList[i], valList[i] );

  /* Probably call function find right here */

   return( 0 );
}

int find( char *key, int *p_ans )
{
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: This looks like homework... You have a hash table that uses a list to address the issue of hash collisions. Your find function would need to iterate over the list for the appropriate hash to see if the key is in there. If so, set the value at the pointed location and return 1. If, having iterated over the list, you find nothing, then return 0. Write it all out in comments, and then slowly convert your comments to working code!

Comment: What help do you specifically need? And "write it for me" is not a valid response. You need to attempt it yourself and come back to ask specific questions if you encounter any problems.

Comment: Who keep down voting this, the OP is only asking for an algorithm IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to write a keycomp function prototype

```
int keycomp (struct data left,struct data right);
```

Return 0 for equals, -1 for L>R and 1 for R>L.

From the origin in your data space chain through comparing the test key to the stored keys.

Because you have a lot I control, ie knowing when a collision happens.
You could just try to store the test key if it goes straight in you know test key has no value stored. Should it collide you need to then do a keycomp against all colliding keys. Note key {2,rhubarb} may have the same hash as {37,dog}.

Remember to delete this newly created dummy test record.

Comment: What dummy test record? Also, there's no need for a three-way comparison function, because the keys are not sorted in any way; just an equality check will suffice.

Comment: You are going to call your store function with test key. This now effectively erroneous record will need to be deleted from the data space.

Comment: Ugh, that's not a good idea, in my opinion. Lookup is a frequent action and also should be read-only. Also, did you notice that the OP's insertion function does not check for duplicate keys? It just slaps a new entry at the beginning of the linked list.

Comment: The only code here was pseudo-c at best when I started here. Overlooked basic stuff like no collision testing, isn't collision detection fundamental to hashing. It may not be the heart or lungs, but it's definitely major like the liver say